# X11 libraries

Tags: linux, x11

I'm running fedora core 9 (64 bit). I need to link to the X11 libraries but they don't seem to be in /usr/lib64/X11 where I'd expect to find them. I thought I installed all the x11 devel stuff in yum, but I can't seem to find the libraries. Anyone know which package it is I need or where to look for them? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devel packages hold header files, not the libraries themselves.

Check the contents of the RPMs you installed with

```
rpm -ql my_rpm
```

That'll show you the files that were in the RPM, so you can see in what directory they landed.

You can get a list of all installed RPMs with

```
rpm -qa
```

so you can grep in it for what you are looking for.